# Running bin/magento s:up results in File "" does not exist

Tags: php, database, bin-magento

I am new to magento and trying to set up a new project locally. After cloning the repo from remote to local, I run composer install and then I try to run bin/magento s:up which runs initially but eventually I get this error.

```
In Gd2Rewrite.php line 57:
                           
File "" does not exist.
```

Tried to find Gd2Rewrite.php but it does not exist in project. Below is the stack trace

```
[2022-12-07T20:11:07.506861+00:00] main.CRITICAL: No cache server(s) could be purged Cache host: star-register-m2.localnet:80resulted in error message: Unable to connect to star-register-m2.localnet:80 . Error #0: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to star-register-m2.localnet:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for star-register-m2.localnet failed: Name or service not known) {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"servers":[{"Laminas\\Uri\\Http":"http://star-register-m2.localnet/"}],"formattedTagsChunk":".*"}} []
[2022-12-07T20:11:07.535551+00:00] main.CRITICAL: No cache server(s) could be purged Cache host: star-register-m2.localnet:80resulted in error message: Unable to connect to star-register-m2.localnet:80 . Error #0: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to star-register-m2.localnet:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for star-register-m2.localnet failed: Name or service not known) {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"servers":[{"Laminas\\Uri\\Http":"http://star-register-m2.localnet/"}],"formattedTagsChunk":".*"}} []
[2022-12-07T20:11:18.536728+00:00] main.CRITICAL: No cache server(s) could be purged Cache host: star-register-m2.localnet:80resulted in error message: Unable to connect to star-register-m2.localnet:80 . Error #0: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to star-register-m2.localnet:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for star-register-m2.localnet failed: Name or service not known) {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"servers":[{"Laminas\\Uri\\Http":"http://star-register-m2.localnet/"}],"formattedTagsChunk":".*"}} []
[2022-12-07T20:11:28.852641+00:00] main.CRITICAL: No cache server(s) could be purged Cache host: star-register-m2.localnet:80resulted in error message: Unable to connect to star-register-m2.localnet:80 . Error #0: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to star-register-m2.localnet:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for star-register-m2.localnet failed: Name or service not known) {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"servers":[{"Laminas\\Uri\\Http":"http://star-register-m2.localnet/"}],"formattedTagsChunk":".*"}} []
[2022-12-07T20:11:28.853614+00:00] main.ERROR: File "" does not exist.
#0 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): MagestyApps\WebImages\Model\Image\Adapter\Gd2Rewrite->open()
#1 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): MagestyApps\WebImages\Model\Image\Adapter\Gd2Rewrite\Interceptor->___callParent()
#2 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): MagestyApps\WebImages\Model\Image\Adapter\Gd2Rewrite\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#3 /var/www/star-register-m2/generated/code/MagestyApps/WebImages/Model/Image/Adapter/Gd2Rewrite/Interceptor.php(23): MagestyApps\WebImages\Model\Image\Adapter\Gd2Rewrite\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#4 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/framework/Image.php(51): MagestyApps\WebImages\Model\Image\Adapter\Gd2Rewrite\Interceptor->open()
#5 /var/www/star-register-m2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Image/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\Image->open()
#6 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/framework/Image.php(36): Magento\Framework\Image\Interceptor->open()
#7 /var/www/star-register-m2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Image/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Framework\Image->__construct()
#8 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\Image\Interceptor->__construct()
#9 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
#10 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#11 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Factory.php(50): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
#12 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Theme/Image.php(127): Magento\Framework\Image\Factory->create()
#13 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme/Registration.php(135): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\Image->createPreviewImage()
#14 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme/Registration.php(114): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->_savePreviewImage()
#15 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme/Registration.php(73): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->_registerThemeRecursively()
#16 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/module-theme/Setup/RecurringData.php(52): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->register()
#17 /var/www/star-register-m2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1117): Magento\Theme\Setup\RecurringData->install()
#18 /var/www/star-register-m2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(960): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData()
#19 /var/www/star-register-m2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DbDataUpgradeCommand.php(69): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures()
#20 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DbDataUpgradeCommand->execute()
#21 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#22 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#23 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#24 /var/www/star-register-m2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#25 /var/www/star-register-m2/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#26 {main} [] []
```

Not sure what the issue is. Thought it could be related to local db. But, mysql is running fine locally and also I have correct credentials for database and correct database name in env.php. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you check my answer on this topic?

Comment: Yes, it did the job. Just had to tweek a bit accordingly. Did not work before but, tried again yesterday. turned out I was doing it the wrong way.

Comment: well done. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gd2Rewrite.php is located in:

- vendor/magestyapps/module-web-images/Model/Image/Adapter/Gd2Rewrite.php in case you install MagestyApps_WebImages module via composer.
- app/code/MagestyApps/WebImages/Model/Image/Adapter/Gd2Rewrite.php in case you install MagestyApps_WebImages module manually in app/code.

Once you found where is it located, run the below command to debug and maybe you are able to resolve the issue immediately:

- `grep -r open vendor/magestyapps/module-web-images` in case you install MagestyApps_WebImages module via composer.
- `grep -r open app/code/MagestyApps/WebImages` in case you install MagestyApps_WebImages module manually in app/code.